# How to evaluate an expression via `LinkWrite` when the expression is only known at runtime?

Tags: evaluation, remote-access, hold

*** Here's the original post...

I'm setting up a secondary kernel in sandbox mode with `LinkLaunch`, and need to pass various expressions to it for evaluation. These expressions are only known at runtime, however (grabbed from notebook cells that the end-user writes). I need to wrap them in `Hold` to prevent evaluation in the main kernel before they get passed off to the secondary via `LinkWrite`. The problem I'm having is that somehow, `ReleaseHold` is ignored when passed through `LinkWrite`. Here's an example:

```
In[17]:= newKernel = LinkLaunch[First[$CommandLine] <> " -wstp -noicon"]

Out[17]= LinkObject["/Applications/Mathematica.app/Contents/MacOS/\ WolframKernel -wstp -noicon", 893, 7]

In[18]:= LinkWrite[newKernel, Unevaluated@EvaluatePacket[Developer`StartProtectedMode[]]]

In[19]:= LinkRead[newKernel]

Out[19]= InputNamePacket["In[1]:= "]

In[20]:= LinkRead[newKernel]

Out[20]= ReturnPacket[Null]

In[21]:= LinkWrite[newKernel, Unevaluated@EvaluatePacket[foo = 2]]

In[22]:= LinkRead[newKernel]

Out[22]= ReturnPacket[2]

In[23]:= LinkWrite[newKernel, Unevaluated@EvaluatePacket[foo^2]]

In[24]:= LinkRead[newKernel]

Out[24]= ReturnPacket[4]

In[25]:= expression = Hold[bar = 3]

Out[25]= Hold[bar = 3]

In[26]:= LinkWrite[newKernel, Unevaluated@EvaluatePacket@ReleaseHold[expression]]

In[27]:= LinkRead[newKernel]

Out[27]= ReturnPacket[Hold[bar = 3]]

In[28]:= LinkWrite[newKernel, Unevaluated@EvaluatePacket[Names[Context[] <> "*"]]]

In[29]:= LinkRead[newKernel]

Out[29]= ReturnPacket[{"expression", "foo"}]

In[30]:= LinkWrite[newKernel, Unevaluated@EvaluatePacket[bar^2]]

In[31]:= LinkRead[newKernel]

Out[31]= ReturnPacket[bar^2]

In[32]:= LinkClose[newKernel]
```

In the line `In[26]`, just as in `In[23]`, the `Unevaluated` prevents the expression from being evaluated in the local kernel *before* it gets passed through the link by `LinkWrite`. I would have expected that when the expression gets to the remote kernel and is evaluated, the `ReleaseHold` will remove the `Hold` and the core definition `bar=3` will be evaluated, defining the symbol `bar`.

That, apparently, is not what happens. As far as I can tell, the `ReleaseHold` is completely ignored. Perhaps someone wiser than I in the dark arts of *Mathematica* delayed evaluation can explain?

And, more importantly, perhaps someone can suggest a workaround so that when I have an expression in held form, I can get it evaluated by the remote kernel?

*** UPDATE: Here's my partial answer and modified question.

Oh, my... I think I just stumbled over the explanation myself. `expression` is not defined in the remote kernel, so it's just an undefined symbol. As far as the remote kernel is concerned, there's no `Hold` to be released!

The reason it looks like I'm getting an unreleased `Hold` back is that `LinkRead` returns the unevaluated `expression`, which is then evaluated here in the local kernel with the definition given above.

Which still leaves me with the problem of how to pass an expression through to the remote kernel for evaluation. All the `LinkWrite` examples I've found in the documentation specify an expression explicitly in the `LinkWrite` call. How can one use `LinkWrite` when the expression to be evaluated must be handled programmatically, i.e., is referred to by a variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple way to inject the value of `expression` into the unevaluated `LinkWrite` argument is to use `With`:

```
Clear[bar]

expression = Hold[bar = 3];

bar

(* bar *)

With[{x = expression},
  LinkWrite[newKernel, Unevaluated@EvaluatePacket[ReleaseHold[x]]]
]
LinkRead[newKernel]

(* ReturnPacket[3] *)

LinkWrite[newKernel, Unevaluated@EvaluatePacket[bar^2]]
LinkRead[newKernel]

(* ReturnPacket[9] *)

bar

(* bar *)
```

**Original Problem**

As noted in the update to the question, the original problem was due to the variable `expression` only being defined within the local kernel.  When the remote kernel was asked to evaluate `ReleaseHold[expression]`, it returned the symbol `expression`.  The local kernel then dutifully evaluated the now unheld symbol `expression` to produce `Hold[bar = 3]`.

Comment: Why does this work? I don't doubt you, but I don't understand why renaming `expression` as `x` changes anything. Within the `EvaluatePacket` statement, they're both equivalent to `Hold[bar=3]`, are they not?

Comment: @ibeatty `With` is purpose-built for this exact situation.  It does more than "simply rename `expression`" -- it evaluates it and then inserts its value into _held expressions_.  This is quite different from, say, `Module` or `Block`.  For details, see [What are the use cases for different scoping constructs?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/559/142).

Comment: Thanks! It seems to work brilliantly, and I shall go read the discussion you linked to. (Again. I've read it a few times before, but each time, what I get out of it depends on what I'm wrestling with at the moment.)

Comment: Um, I spoke too soon. When I try, it looks like `bar` is being given a value of `3` in the local content, not in the sandbox. Try `bar^2` locally, and then do `Clear[bar]` locally and try `LinkWrite[newKernel, Unevaluated@EvaluatePacket[bar^2]]` again. I just get `ReturnPacket[bar^2]`. 8-(

Comment: Yes, you are right.  I forgot about the use of `Unevaluated`.  The `With` has to be wrapped around the whole `LinkWrite` expression to avoid prematurely stripping `Unevaluated`.  I have adjusted to response accordingly.

Comment: Okay, that does seem to work properly now. Thanks again. Was the problem with `Unevaluated` that it needs to wrap the entirety of an argument to `LinkWrite` in order to work properly and suppress `LinkWrite`'s evaluation of the argument?

Comment: That is correct.  When `Unevaluated` appeared directly within the `With`, it was removed when the inner `With` expression was evaluated, but before the `LinkWrite` was evaluated.  Thus, the `ReleaseHold` was no longer being protected from local evaluation.  By making `With` the outer expression, `Unevaluated` remains in place while the `LinkWrite` is evaluated.